# remove and add class with linear easing is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Not able to control the linear easing in remove class as well as add class $("#masthead").removeClass("header_bottom", 700, "linear");

Here is my site http://developermobulous.com link  you can check on scroll the header comes but it goes little above to the default top and little below to the default bottom.

Answer will be really appreciating

Comment: did you inlcude  jquery ui   `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

then only you have to animate in remove class

Comment: If you want to remove/add class on animate element you need to do that on callback. $( element ).animate({property: value
}, 700, function() { // here remove/add class code }); Read here http://api.jquery.com/animate/  If you use jqueryUI check as Manishankar said

Comment: see jquery api doc http://api.jqueryui.com/removeclass/

Answer (score 1):

`$.removeClass` is not an animating function. You should only use `$("#masthead").removeClass("header_bottom");`

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any reference of [jquery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/download/all/) in your site. You have to include that to work with [`.removeClass( className [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) function. Otherwise its just invoking jquery api [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/).

Comment: I have that script in the header <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Finally I got the way to make it stable, because fixed header goes on beyond the top because of speed when I put less speed i.e 400 then everything is fine but still it depends how fast to move the scroll.